# Texmaker's internal PDF-viewer keeps file handler to .pdf open and hinders subsequent compilings

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker, viewers

After updating to Texmaker 4.0.4 today, I am no longer able to compile my PDFs more than once per Texmaker session. I need to quit Texmaker and run it again to compile again. The error I get is the same as when you try to compile, but have the file opened in an external reader.

I am using the internal PDF-viewer and have not changed any Texmaker settings. To compile my work I use the quick build feature set to run pdflatex and view pdf.

I did not have this problem before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download the most recent windows packages ( [on the download page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#windows) ).
The windows packages of Texmaker 4.0.4 has been recompiled with poppler 0.22 because of a bug in the windows version of poppler 0.24 (pdf are locked).

Comment: The OP states the/she's already using 4.0.4....

Comment: The answer says : "The windows packages of Texmaker 4.0.4 has been REcompiled". Because of the bug of the windows version of poppler 0.24, the windows bundle packages of Texmaker 4.0.4 (and only them) have been rebuild to contain poppler 0.22 instead of poppler 0.24 (nothing has changed in the texmaker program, except that it is linked with poppler 0.22 instead of poppler 0.24). Downloading the current packages available on the project home site will fix the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot! i would not have expected such a fast answer and also fast reaction by the Texmaker team. kudos and thanks! the problem has been solved.

Comment: With Sumatra, no conflict with Texmaker online viewer. Better than Adobe.